# Is there any shortcut for focusing on specific repository in VSCode source control side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

In vscode, I use a multi-root workspace with 40+ different git repositories. I use vscode source control extensively. My current workflow is to scroll through the source control repositories to find the correct repository and click on it. This could be a little time consuming and annoying if there are many repositories and if you context switch often. Is it possible to do this without scrolling?

I am looking for a shortcut where I could type the repo name. Or a setting or an extension that focus on the correct repository based on open file in editor.

I looked through the git shortcuts in vscode but none of them worked.